# How to add external library to android studio? and if able to add. how can i update external library if got changes?

Tags: java, android-studio, module, gitlab, dependencies

How to add an external library to the android studio? and if able to add. how can I update the external library if got changes?. for your information. my external library is in private GitLab. so in case, I got changes in my external library I just push the code. and later when open the android studio. I want the changes I have made already in the external library in android studio. how can I achieve this?

Comment: You put dependencies in build.gradle, and I don't think Android Studio just automatically updates them since you specify the version (you can use a plus though that may lead to repeated builds).

Comment: All Right understood that.  I also don't think it will automatically update. but maybe need to do something I guess in order to update the library right?

Comment: As far as I know, you would have to manually update it (by changing the version).